# Why is Unknown Timezone shown in R

Tags: r, timezone

I am doing high frequency checks on a survey dataset. When I am checking for surveys that show start time earlier than first day of data collection, a warning message comes up saying,

> "In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%y'"

. The code I have used is:

```
subset(subset(Level1, as.Date(Level1$starttime, "%m/%d/%y") < as.Date("7/31/21", "%m/%d/%y")),
       select= c("b_en_id", "starttime","endtime", "child_name")
       )
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the class of the column "starttime" is not character (but POSIXct I guess). You can check it :

```
class(Level1$starttime)
```

so the 2nd argument will be tz (timezone) and not format, you can see it in the documentation of `as.Date` function : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date